# How to make a folder behave like a top-level drive?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I've got a couple of .swf files (not created by me) that are linked together not relatively, but *absolutely*.

By that, I mean that the file `D:/file1.swf` links to `D:/file2.swf` through an absolute link:

```
/file2.swf
```

Thus, when I move `D:/file1.swf` to `E:/Swf Collection/file1.swf`, and `D:/file2.swf` to `E:/Swf Collection/file2.swf`, **the hyperlink stopped working** (it now points to `E:/file2.swf` instead of `E:/Swf Collection/file2.swf`).

How do I simulate the folder `E:/Swf Collection` such that it behaves like a *top-level* drive so that the hyperlink would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the old `subst` command (available since ancient DOS times).

```
cd e:
subst d: "Swf Collection"
```

Example usage of subst can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true). That documentation is for XP, but I just tested it on windows 7 and it also works there.

Comment: Ah! The classics! It'll be a sad day indeed when Microsoft users lose the command-line! A very useful tool is subst.

Comment: But when the file is moved to another computer, it would no longer work right..

Comment: Correct. You are making the changes to your computer and they take effect on your computer only. If you want to move the SWF files to other computers and have them work there then you want to change the SWF files. Edit them and replace the absolute paths to relative paths.   (But that was not the question asked in the post).